# Thread throw System.OutOfMemoryException in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, out-of-memory

The following code will call another thread when the application doing the processing to show the progress windows. It will throw an exception after we do multiple time, for example hit more than 50 times. 
This is our code - BusyIndicatorHelper.ShowProgWindowCustomSize as thrown from the exception and will call the following code.

```
public void ShowBusyIndicatorCustomSize(string message, WindowCustom currentWindow, bool fileTransferStatus = false)
{
    _message = message;
    using (_progressWindowWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
    {
        _transferLoadVisibility = fileTransferStatus;
        //Starts the progress window thread
        Thread newprogWindowThread = new Thread(() => ShowProgWindowCustomSize(currentWindow));  
        //new Thread(new ThreadStart(ShowProgWindowNew(height, width, left, right)));
        newprogWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        newprogWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
        newprogWindowThread.Start();

        //Wait for thread to notify that it has created the window
        _progressWindowWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        _isActive = true;
    }
}
```

This will call ShowProgWindowCustomSize(currentWindow) as in the following.

```
private void ShowProgWindowCustomSize(WindowCustom currentWindow)
    {
        if (_transferLoadVisibility)
        {
            //creates and shows the progress window
            progWindow = new LoadingWindow(_message);
            progWindow.Height = currentWindow.WindowHeight;
            progWindow.Width = currentWindow.WindowWidth;
            progWindow.Left = currentWindow.WindowLeft;
            progWindow.Top = currentWindow.WindowTop;
            progWindow.WindowState = currentWindow.WindowState;

            progWindow.FileTansfer();
            progWindow.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            //creates and shows the progress window
            progWindow = new LoadingWindow(_message);
            progWindow.Height = currentWindow.WindowHeight;
            progWindow.Width = currentWindow.WindowWidth;
            progWindow.Left = currentWindow.WindowLeft;
            progWindow.Top = currentWindow.WindowTop;
            progWindow.WindowState = currentWindow.WindowState;
            progWindow.Show();
        }

        //makes sure dispatcher is shut down when the window is closed
        progWindow.Closed += (s, e) => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);

        //Notifies command thread the window has been created
        _progressWindowWaitHandle.Set();

        //Starts window dispatcher
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    }
```

The following are the outofmemory exception being thrown.

> Application: BioMedicalVerification.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.OutOfMemoryException Stack: at
>   System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE+Channel.SyncFlush() at
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.CompleteRender() at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize() at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage
>   (MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr) at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage (IntPtr,
>   Int32,  IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc
>   (IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object) at 
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall
>   (System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen (System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl
>   (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, 
>   IntPtr, IntPtr) at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DefWndProcWrapper(IntPtr,
>   Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr) at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, 
>   IntPtr, IntPtr) at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr,
>   Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr) at  MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.SetWindowPos
>   (System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef,
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32,
>   Int32) at System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double, Double,
>   Double, Double) at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean)
>   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow() at
>   System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow() at
>   System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(System.Object) at
>   System.Windows.Window.Show() at
>   Org.Bestinet.BV.Presentation.UI.BusyIndicatorHelper.ShowProgWindowCustomSize
>   (Org.Bestinet.BV.Presentation.UI.WindowCustom) at
>   Org.Bestinet.BV.Presentation.UI.BusyIndicatorHelper+<>
>   c__DisplayClass2.<ShowBusyIndicatorCustomSize>b__0() at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,  System.Threading.ContextCallback,
>   System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, 
>   System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, 
>   System.Object) at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

I suspect because of the VerifyFinger function as this is where we do the checking for the finger print image

```
BusyIndicatorHelper busyIndicatorHelper = new BusyIndicatorHelper();
List<WorkerDO> docList = new         
DatabaseHelper().SearchDocInfo(UserContext.VdrInfo.WorkerObj.WrkrId);

if (docList != null && docList.Count > 0)
{   busyIndicatorHelper.ShowBusyIndicatorCustomSize("Verification",  
    WindowSetting.GetCurrentWindowState(this));

    FingerPrintHelper fp = null;
    if (_fpHelper != null)
       fp = _fpHelper;
    else
       fp = FingerPrintHelper.GetFingerPrinterHelperObj;

    verifyStatus = fp.VerifyFinger(docList, _viewModel.DetectedFingers,  
    IsIndexFingerSelected);
    docList = null;
    _viewModel.DetectedFingers = null;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely not related to that "wait" dialog, but to logic being executed while this window is displayed. You show us the source code for that window, which does not make any sense. You should instead show what is going on while this window is displayed

Comment: Can you share WindowCustom code? Both XAML and codebehind? It might be related to what is happening inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was found. It's not because of the WPF code but due the SDK that we are using out of memory.

Issue resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you close the `CurrentDispatcher`? It's the only one for your program, and your code will never execute the shutdown. So each time you open your `BusyWindow`, the new thread is being created (- `1MB` from your memory), and it falls into infinite loop, which consumes another part of system resources. Eventually your program will get out of the memory, which is happen, as your exception states.

You really should not start a new thread for your task - use higher lever of abstraction, may be [`ThreadPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) or [`Task Parallel Library`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). this will help remove memory leaks from your code.

**Update:**
I see in your new code such line:

```
_viewModel.DetectedFingers = null;
```

I suspect that this is an [`Image`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) you got from client. If so, you can't simply set it to `null`, you must [`Dispose()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8th8381z.aspx) it to free your graphical resources, like this:

```
verifyStatus = fp.VerifyFinger(docList, _viewModel.DetectedFingers,  
IsIndexFingerSelected);
docList = null;
_viewModel.DetectedFingers.Dispose();
_viewModel.DetectedFingers = null;
```

Comment: _viewModel.DetectedFingers is a list of FingerPrintDetails object which contain image object as well. I think probably because of this and will dispose it and update the result here.

Comment: Even after dispose the image object in _viewModel.DetectedFingers list still not resolve the issue. Still got out of memory at the following line of code
        progWindow.Closed += (s, e) => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);

Comment: Then remove thread creation, as I've stated before - you got many threads, which aren't closing right way, as it seems to me.

Answer (score -1):

Each time you call this method you are creating a new LoadingWindow object on a new thread.

progWindow = new LoadingWindow(_message);

Are you freeing the prior LoadingWindow before creating the new one?

Comment: I have close the thread using the following code and it was standard code to close the thread.  public void HideBusyIndicator()
        {
            //closes the Progress window
           if(_isActive)
            progWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(progWindow.Close));
          
           _isActive = false;
        }